# On the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

An exact solution could be found if only one were able to solve
$$\int_0^te^{at'}\mathrm{d}W_{t'} $$
Using Ito's lemma, it's possible to convert the former to the following deterministic integral
$$
\int_{0}^t e^{at'}W_{t'}\mathrm{d}t'
$$
net of boundary terms.
This procedure however shifts the problem but doesn't solve it. And simply calculating the mean and variance wouldn't solve it either, since for each given $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ there are infinite different processes sharing these same numbers while being completely different from one another.

So? How should this be done?

Comment: That term is considered satisfactory because: (i) it does not contain the OU process in it; (ii) we know its distribution and its autocovariance structure. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to find a result, like for any other stochastic integral. Here are some examples: $$\int_0^te^{s/2}\cos(W_s)\mathrm{d}W_s=e^{t/2}\sin(W_t)$$ $$\int_0^te^{-s/2+W_s}\mathrm{d}W_s=e^{-t/2+W_t}-1$$ $$\int_0^t(W_s^2-s)\mathrm{d}W_s=\frac{W_t^3}{3}-tW_t$$

Comment: Getting an explicit expression for a stochastic integral is extremely rare and one should not expect it to be possible for most integrands.